# Cannot use function to update object

Tags: javascript

I've created a function `change` which can be used to change the `name` of the object `person`.

There is one argument for the function and this argument would be the new name for the object.

But the new name I pass into this argument becomes `...is not defined`, what am I missing here?

**Edited**
`thisIsNewName` is a string and this is to replace `Ali`.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Ali',
  Age: '18'
}

function change(text) {
  person.name = text;
}

change(thisIsNewName);

console.log(person.name);
```

Comment: Please fix `ReferenceError: thisIsNewName is not defined`. Where do you define `thisIsNewName`? What is the value of `thisIsNewName`? You can't call `person.name(text);`. It's not a function. It's a string. You probably want to assign `person.name = text;`

Comment: @jabaa What do you mean? The `thisIsNewName` is a string and I wanna replace this with `Ali`

Comment: `person.name` isn't a function, so don't use parenthesis. Change it to `person.name = text;`

Comment: Why do you expect `thisIsNewName` to be a string? Do you mean `'thisIsNewName'`?

Comment: @Gil It's still not working

Comment: @jabaa I think I've made it quite clear: I wanna replace the `Ali` which is done by the function. And `thisIsNewName` is just an example, it could be anything to replace `Ali`, which part you do not understand?

Comment: I don't understand the part, why you expect this code to work when you don't define the variable `thisIsNewName`. When I initialize the variable or use a string instead, I don't get the error message. I don't understand what you not understand. You got a description of both problems in your code and how to fix both.

Comment: Don't apply the answers to your questions to fix your code. Now, both answers doesn't make sense and the code in your questions works. I rollback your last change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass argument that you did not define. You can create variable or you can pass directly string to it

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Ali',
  Age: '18'
}

function change(text) {
  person.name = text;
}

let thisIsNewName = 'ALI2';
change(thisIsNewName);


//Or you can pass directly string
//change("thisIsNewName");


console.log(person.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `thisIsNewName` is a string and this is to replace Ali.

No, it's not.

`thisIsNewName` is not defined in your code.

Either define the variable and assign a string

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Ali',
  Age: '18'
}

function change(text) {
  person.name = text;
}

const thisIsNewName = 'newName';
change(thisIsNewName);

console.log(person.name);
```

or call the function with a string literal

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Ali',
  Age: '18'
}

function change(text) {
  person.name = text;
}

change('thisIsNewName');
console.log(person.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the name as a string if you meant it like this -> `change("thisIsNewName")`
But if you want to pass a variable to the function then define it before using: `let thisIsNewName = "new name"`

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Ali',
  Age: '18'
}

function change(text) {
  person.name = text;
}

change("thisIsNewName"); //*

console.log(person.name);
```

or

```js
    const person = {
      name: 'Ali',
      Age: '18'
    }

    function change(text) {
      person.name = text;
    }
    
    let thisIsNewName = "new name";//*
    change(thisIsNewName);

    console.log(person.name);
```